# Error on ManyToMany association

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I'm trying to add a new manager from admin to my application but I'm having this error :

```
The property "nurseries" in class "VS\CrmBundle\Entity\Staff" can be defined with the methods "addNurseries()", "removeNurseries()" but the new value must be an array or an instance of \Traversable, "VS\CrmBundle\Entity\Nursery" given.
```

I have a `ManyToMany` association between Nursery and Staff classes :

```
class Staff extends User
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Nursery", inversedBy="staff", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="nursery_staff",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="staff_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="nursery_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *  )
     */
    private $nurseries;

    /**
     * Staff constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->nurseries = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    /**
     * @param Nursery $nursery
     */
    public function addNurseries(Nursery $nursery)
    {
        $nursery->addStaff($this);
        $this->nurseries[] = $nursery;
    }

    /**
     * @param Nursery $nursery
     */
    public function removeNurseries(Nursery $nursery)
    {
        $this->nurseries->removeElement($nursery);
    }

    /**
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getNurseries()
    {
        return $this->nurseries;
    }
```

And :

```
class Nursery
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Staff", mappedBy="nurseries", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="nursery_staff")
     */
    private $staff;
    /**
     * Nursery constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->staff = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->schedule = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
        $this->contacts = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->registerRecord = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    /**
     * Add staff
     *
     * @param \VS\CrmBundle\Entity\Staff $staff
     *
     * @return Nursery
     */
    public function addStaff(\VS\CrmBundle\Entity\Staff $staff)
    {
        $this->staff[] = $staff;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove staff
     *
     * @param \VS\CrmBundle\Entity\Staff $staff
     */
    public function removeStaff(\VS\CrmBundle\Entity\Staff $staff)
    {
        $this->staff->removeElement($staff);
    }

    /**
     * Get staff
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getStaff()
    {
        return $this->staff;
    }
```

Then I have this controller :

```
   public function addAction(Request $request)
    {
        //Create the forms
        $manager = new Staff();
        $managerForm = $this->get('form.factory')->create(StaffFromAdminType::class, $manager);

        $managerForm->handleRequest($request);
        if($managerForm->isSubmitted() && $managerForm->isValid())
        {
            $manager->setStaffRole('MANAGER');

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($manager);
            $em->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'The Manager has been successfully added.');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('vs_crm_admin_dashboard');
        }

        return $this->render("VSCrmBundle:Admin/Manager:add-manager.html.twig", array(
            'manager_form' => $managerForm->createView()
        ));
    }
```

and finally this is my form :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('firstName')
        ->add('lastName')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('addresses', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' =>  AddressType::class,
            'allow_add' => true
        ))
        /*
        ->add('medias', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => MediaType::class,
            'allow_add' => true
        ))*/
        ->add('staffRole')
        ->add('nurseries', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'VSCrmBundle:Nursery',
        ));
}
```

and this log :

```
[1] Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\Exception\NoSuchPropertyException: The property "nurseries" in class "VS\CrmBundle\Entity\Staff" can be defined with the methods "addNurseries()", "removeNurseries()" but the new value must be an array or an instance of \Traversable, "VS\CrmBundle\Entity\Nursery" given.
    at n/a
        in C:\wamp64\www\app\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor.php line 614

    at Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor->writeProperty(array(object(Staff), object(Staff)), 'nurseries', object(Nursery))
        in C:\wamp64\www\app\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor.php line 202

    at Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor->setValue(object(Staff), object(PropertyPath), object(Nursery))
        in C:\wamp64\www\app\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataMapper\PropertyPathMapper.php line 93

    at Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataMapper\PropertyPathMapper->mapFormsToData(object(RecursiveIteratorIterator), object(Staff))
        in C:\wamp64\www\app\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Form.php line 618

    at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->submit(array('nurseries' => '1', 'firstName' => 'Jacques', 'lastName' => 'Dupont', 'email' => 'viktor@test.be', '_token' => 'tULa-SoBQArpx34h9d5gNOi93t2gXw_ZSlsdc52Fvus'), true)
        in C:\wamp64\www\app\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\HttpFoundation\HttpFoundationRequestHandler.php line 113

    at Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\HttpFoundation\HttpFoundationRequestHandler->handleRequest(object(Form), object(Request))
        in C:\wamp64\www\app\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Form.php line 488

    at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->handleRequest(object(Request))
        in C:\wamp64\www\app\src\VS\CrmBundle\Controller\ManagerController.php line 36

    at VS\CrmBundle\Controller\ManagerController->addAction(object(Request))
        in  line 

    at call_user_func_array(array(object(ManagerController), 'addAction'), array(object(Request)))
        in C:\wamp64\www\app\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel.php line 153

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1')
        in C:\wamp64\www\app\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel.php line 68

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
        in C:\wamp64\www\app\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php line 169

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
        in C:\wamp64\www\app\web\app_dev.php line 28
```

So I just want the admin to choose the right nursery in a list of all the registered nurseries, add some data for the new manager and save the manager with with the link between the new manager and an existing nursery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are generating elemtment of Object `nursery` in form. Instead you need to pass array of `nursery`. Try after adding `'multiple' => true` in `FormType`.

**FormType**

```
->add('nurseries', EntityType::class, array(
     'multiple' => true,     
     'class' => 'VSCrmBundle:Nursery'
))
```

**Note:** `'multiple' => true` will create array type control instead of object.