# Symfony ManyToMany with entity type

Tags: php, entity, symfony

I have a problem with my code. I have this error :

```
The property "users" in class "Wiki\AdminBundle\Entity\Post" can be defined with the methods "addUser()", "removeUser()" but the new value must be an array or an instance of \Traversable, "Wiki\AdminBundle\Entity\User" given.
```

I don't understand what's happened with my code.

This is my FormType :

```
<?php

namespace Wiki\AdminBundle\Form;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Tests\Fixtures\Entity;
use Wiki\AdminBundle\Entity\Post;

class PostType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('users', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => 'WikiAdminBundle:User',
                'choice_label' => 'username',
            ])
            ->add('status')
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Post::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And here my Post Entity :

```
<?php

namespace Wiki\AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Wiki\AdminBundle\Traits\Entity as EntityTraits;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="post")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Wiki\AdminBundle\Entity\Repository\PostRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Post
{
    use EntityTraits\IdTrait;
    use EntityTraits\DateCreated;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="text")
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Wiki\AdminBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="posts", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\Column(name="author", type="text")
     */
    private $users;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="integer")
     */
    private $status;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $title
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $status
     */
    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;
    }

    public function addUser(User $user)
    {
        $this->users->add($user);
        $user->addPost($this);
    }

    public function removeUser(User $user)
    {
        $this->users->removeElement($user);
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }
}
```

Can someone help me to resolve my problem ?

best regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It requires array while storing data in datatable but you have passed `user` object. Add `'multiple' => true` in form builder for 'users`.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title')
        ->add('users', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => 'WikiAdminBundle:User',
            'multiple' => true,
            'choice_label' => 'username',
        ])
        ->add('status')
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
    ;
}
```

**Note:** `'multiple' => true` will create array type control instead of object.

[Ref Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41344275/2689199)